# Screen.PixelPerInch anomalies in Delphi

Tags: delphi, highdpi

If I run my program under debugger, the Screen.PixelPerInch is always 96 DPI.
If I run as an exe, it is 144 DPI. How could I run under debugger with the same 144 DPI value?
For design purposes, the UI designer uses fixed 96 DPI. It is right. But the running code under debugger? It is not right.

I use Delphi 11.1.5. under Win 10 as a mortal user (not as admin). I enabled the compatibility/HDI setting (System) at the bds.exe link (to avoid form resizing by form designers on computers with different DPI settings). I use the default manifest settings (dynamic + per monitor)

Comment: Delphi 11.5? Are you a time traveller from the future? Does this version work properly???

Comment: Do you have different High DPI settings for Debug and Release?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 11.1.5 Sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: @UweRaabe It is the same exe. I just start it by F9 from delphi  (1sf case) and from total commander (2nd case).

Comment: It works as expected here (Delphi 11.2) as it did with the versions before (f.i. Delphi 11.1). As long as it is not 11.1.5 specific, it must be caused by something you didn't tell us yet.

Comment: @UweRaabe I should use UFO computers because it works for me always in the same way with all the versions of delphi on all of my computers. i added some details to the question.

Comment: You should see a Delphi (DPI unaware) entry in your programs menu. Try with that one instead fiddling around with the compatibility settings.

Answer (score 0):

> I enabled the compatibility/HDI setting (System) at the bds.exe link (to avoid form resizing by form designers on computers with different DPI settings). I use the default manifest settings (dynamic + per monitor)

Compatibility settings are inherited by child processes and override their manifests.

To fix your issue you should disable compatibility setting for bds.exe and use "/highdpi:unaware" parameter. That way you will get the same result as before, but child processes will behave as specified by their manifests.

Comment: Yes, but in this case the IDE appears by unreadable micro captions and icons. And the size values in forms rescaled at open.

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper Can it be that you are running some old version of Windows?

Comment: Is the recently updated Win 10 an old version nowadays? :)

Comment: I am just guessing what "unreadable micro captions and icons" could mean. Can you provide some screenshot?